# How to create recurring charges via stripe python api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stripe-payments

Right now I have the following code that creates a customer and then charges them $5 via the stripe api for python:

```
# amount in cents
amount = 500

customer = stripe.Customer.create(
    email='sample@customer.com',
    source=request.form['stripeToken']
)

stripe.Charge.create(
    customer=customer.id,
    amount=amount,
    currency='usd',
    description='Flask Charge'
)
```

I want to change this to create a recurring monthly charge for the same $5 per month.

I can't find any example of how to do this in python except for Stripe Connect which is a marketplace platform and not what i need. I am a business and I want to charge consumers $5 directly to be paid to my business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are happy with Stripe Billing's simple model of Product and Plan, you can probably use that instead of Stripe Connect.

This is sufficiently involved that I don't think it's a great idea to replicate the whole process here, but each essential step is described in the [Billing Quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart).

As an example, setting up a plan, once you have a product defined, is a simple API call:

```py
# Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
# See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'

plan = stripe.Plan.create(
  product='prod_CbvTFuXWh7BPJH',
  nickname='SaaS Platform USD',
  interval='month',
  currency='usd',
  amount=10000,
)
```

Once you have a plan, and as in your own example, a customer, instead of creating a Charge you create a Subscription:

```py
subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
  customer='cus_4fdAW5ftNQow1a',
  items=[{'plan': 'plan_CBXbz9i7AIOTzr'}],
)
```

You should set up webhook URLs so that your own service is notified whether a customer's subscription is active, incomplete, or in another state.

Comment: I hope this is not your real test key. ;)

Comment: @Clemens it's literally copy and pasted sample code from the URL linked above, so no, it's definitely not my key.

Comment: Oh no, Stzripe cresates individual exaymples dynamically for every user. So this is definitely your test key.

Comment: Given I've never logged into Stripe on the machine that I wrote the answer on, I seriously doubt it. But since it's a test key and not the production key, it's moot.

Comment: Even if it had only a very small probability that it is really your test key, I wouldn't take the risk of distributing it on a publicly accessible website.